# How should I structure/organize a complex python project?

Tags: python, project, project-organization

## Problem

I can't wrap my head around this problem, my project is fairly complex and I can't find a way to organize it in order to fill my needs.

I understand this might be very broad statement, so I'll show what I did and then explain the task at hand...

## How it's currently organized

Project

- docs (useful documentation)
- images (needed for the project)
- tests (might be useful)
- main.py
- utils

1. **init**.py
2. class.py
3. accuracy.py
4. template_matching.py
5. homography.py
6. sorting_2d.py

## Task

I separated my problem into smaller ones:

1. Compute homography
2. Perform template matching
3. 2D sorting
4. Compute accuracy

I also have a class that is used all across the previously enumerated, some however, need their own class that is only used in 1 file.

I don't know how to organize it better, I feel it's not congruent enough and I might be missing a standard procedure here... I fear it will become hard to interpret or crumble into a pile of spaghetti errors.

If anyone could indicate similar problems that I can take as an example would be great.
Or even try to figure how you would organize this one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems fine, without seeing the code in the various files it's hard to say more. Breaking things up by task or theme as you have done is a good start. Think in terms of a dependency graph, or a data flow (e.g. series of tasks). If the task files have to import various things from each other then the division might not be optimal. If each task only imports things from one other 'adjacent' task (perhaps plus things from a shared 'utils' module) it's probably ok, i.e. there is a consistent 'direction' to the imports.

Comment: ...another approach might be to avoid any 'lateral' imports between task modules and instead have a main 'orchestrator' module that is the entry point, which imports from all the tasks and runs them in correct order